# Detection job run, no notification emailed

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

When starting a duplicate detection job, I'm checking *notify when done*. After the job's finished, no email is received at the address mentioned at the start of the job. I'm logging in using AD and authorization is done the same way as Exchange is using, so I expected the email to work.

I tried to approve the mail recipient (me) when creating the user. To no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you find email in activities waiting to be send? As far as i can remeber both: sender and recipient need to have valid email, so you might want if sender is valid as well

Comment: Hmm... Not sure where to check this (system jobs? I didn't see anything there...) but I'm sure you're on the right track because now, when I log onto the organization, I get the error message that there's a bunch of mails waiting to be sent. Do I have to configure the router? Never done that... Will that be resolved by installing the client for Outlook? (Even if so, not all users will be able to do that since some are using OWA...)

Comment: So seems like they are just not being send. You have to either set up email router, server side sync or have outlook with plugin. On user record you have to tell which method do you use. For users with OWA router or server-side would be only options.

Comment: What is the "server-side sync"? Also, please post this as a reply so I can give you some reputation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So seems like they are just not being send. You have to either set up email router, server side sync or have outlook with plugin. On user record you have to tell which method do you use. For users with OWA router or server-side would be only options.

Server-side is new in 2013. It can replace email router, so all email processing is done by async service.

Comment: +1 for the news on server-side, which I wasn't ware of at all.